# Call function with a click of a button flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Im very new to flask and im trying to convert a python tkinter gui app to web.
As you can understand i have all the functions made so it would be great if a could call them and pass variables with a single click of a button.

for example:

get_sub_menu is a list generated by a query to the db where it stores [('1','name1'),('2','name2'),('3','name3')]

mod[0] = id

mod[1] = name

html file:

```
<html><head></head><body>

{% for mod in get_sub_menu %}
<button type="submit">{{ mod[1] }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

when i click in one button he should submit the id(mod[0]) and call function(myid) where myid would be the id submited when the button is clicked in order to generate the second list of buttons.

```
{% for item in function(mod[0]) %}
<button type="submit">{{ item[1] }}</button> #function(mod[0])
{% endfor %}

</body><html>
```

py file:

```
def function(myid):

    select * from table where id=myid

    res = cursor.fetchall()

    return res
```

should i do this with request or args?
can anyone help me with bouth questions in order for me to learn and understand why one is better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

lol maybe you should leave python and dedicate yourself to

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).